# is it okay to add icon credits in the "About" screen of a commercial Mobile App

Tags: icons

just a quick question, i know this is usually done on a website but is it okay to add icon credits in the "about" screen of a mobile Application espercially for paid Apps like in Iphone or android. Has anybody seen this being done?. just wondering if it sounds professional. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your icons are probably licenced under LGPL or Creative Commons and this is exactly what these licences suggest for putting the credits.

Comment: thanks for your response. please see the comment i made in the previous answer. thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Most places that require you to "credit" them if you use their IP don't specify the place in your app that this credit should show up.  Normally in desktop apps, the about page is a reliable place to find these credits.  I believe the about page in a mobile app is also a reliable place.  So unless the icons you have to credit specify the manner in which you need to credit them, this seems ok.

Comment: yeah, i know you are free to put it anywhere. i actually had the end consumer in mind when asking the question, whether it seems odd to them. thats why i was asking if anyone had come across it.

Comment: No one looks into the about dialog and those who do, do it because they want to know for example about the icons.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple recommends](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) you don't use the loading screen as an about or splash screen:

> Supply a launch image to improve user
>   experience; **avoid** using it as an
>   opportunity to provide:
>
> > An “application entry experience,”
> >     such as a splash screen
> >
> > An About window
> >
> > Branding elements, unless they
> >     are a static part of your
> >     application’s first screen

(my emphasis)

I suggest you keep such icons and references to components on the developer web page about the product, rather than in the application itself.